# Prove inequality: $2\Big[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1) a_k \Big]^2 -\Big[1+ \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \Big]\Big[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} k(k+1)a_k \Big] \geq 0.$

Tags: inequalities, convex-geometry, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $a_0\geq\dots \geq a_n \geq 0$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers, where $n+1\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \leq n+2$. Then, I want to prove that the following statement is true,

$2\Big[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1) a_k \Big]^2 -\Big[1+ \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \Big]\Big[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} k(k+1)a_k \Big] \geq 0.$

Comment: Do not use $N$ where $n$ will do. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Why?

Comment: @IosifPinelis - you introduced a typo into the title ...

Comment: @mathworker21 : (i) There is no reason to use $N$ where $n$ will do. (ii) For each entry of $n$ instead of $N$, one keystroke is saved.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt : Fixed it.

Comment: @IosifPinelis lol. (i) is not a reason, just a restatement. In analytic number theory, one will often sum over $n$ in the range $n \in [N,2N)$, and will write $n \sim N$ as shorthand, in the bottom of the summation. It is very useful (psychologically, of course) to have lower case letters be of the same size as their upper case counterparts.

Comment: @mathworker21 : Let me rephrase (i): where using $N$ instead of $n$ is not an advantage, why use $N$ instead of $n$? Does this question sound reasonable to you? In your example, using $N$ along with $n$ does seem an advantage, and there using $n$ in place of $N$ would certainly not do. In contrast, in the OP on this page, using $n$ in place of $N$ certainly works quite well. So, your example is about something that I never said or meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A counterexample is given by the following conditions: $n=185$,
$$a_k=\sum_{j=k}^n b_j,\quad b_j:=\frac{c_j}{j+1},
\quad c_j:=\frac{1000}7\,1(j=47)+\frac{302}7\,1(j=185).$$

---

Indeed, then $a_0\ge\cdots\ge a_n\ge0$,
$$s_0:=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=k}^n b_j
=\sum_{j=0}^n b_j\sum_{k=0}^j 1 \\
=\sum_{j=0}^n b_j(j+1)
=\sum_{j=0}^n c_j=\frac{1000}7+\frac{302}7=186\in[n+1,n+2],$$
$$s_1:=\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)a_k=\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)\sum_{j=k}^n b_j
=\sum_{j=0}^n b_j\sum_{k=0}^j(k+1) \\
=\sum_{j=0}^n b_j\frac{(j+1)(j+2)}2
=\sum_{j=0}^n c_j\frac{j+2}2=\frac{105474}7,$$
$$s_2:=\sum_{k=0}^n k(k+1)a_k=\sum_{k=0}^n k(k+1)\sum_{j=k}^n b_j
=\sum_{j=0}^n b_j\sum_{k=0}^j k(k+1) \\
=\sum_{j=0}^n b_j\frac{j(j+1)(j+2)}3
=\sum_{j=0}^n c_j\frac{j(j+2)}3=\frac{4250230}7,$$
so that the left-hand side of your inequality is
$$2s_1^2-(1+s_0)s_2=-\frac{1168732}{49}<0.\quad\Box$$

Comment: Hey. Thank you so much for the counter example. I was trying to prove convexity of a function and the inequality above comes out as the part of the second derivative. Probably the convexity argument is not true then. I was trying to see if i can establish some more conditions on my actual function that can help me get rid of the counter examples like above. But, probably that is not prossible.